# Is it correct that page elements created by jQuery do not show up in the source code

Tags: jquery

I have the following code (snippet):

```
 var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
for(var page =0; page < numPages; page++) {
 $('<span class="page-number">' + (page + 1) + '</span>')
  .appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
  }
 $pager.insertBefore($table);
```

Is it correct that when I view the page source I don't see the `"<div class="...` code?

Comment: not in the "View Source" but will in the HTML view in Firebug or IE Developer Toolbar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The source is just used to build the initial [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) that represents the document. Dynamically created elements are only inserted in the DOM.

But you can analyse such elements with a DOM viewer like Safari’s WebInspector or the Firefox extionsion Firebug. Firefox can also show source code that represents such dynamically created elements by selecting that element an choosing *View Selection Source* in the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they do NOT show up,

elements created with javascript arent't visible in the 'View source' part of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.

In firefox you can see the latest source by selecting everything on the page (ctrl+a) and then using rightmouse+view selection source. Or even better, you should install firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The elements are added directly to the DOM, and not visible via normal view source.

Answer (score 1):

You could use FireBug to find it if you needed to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, after pressing F12 and then in HTML section you can press the refresh button to see the updated code.