# Dynamically add option with jquery and update html source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have two listbox, **A** & **B**:

[image]

when I double click on an item of **A** , the item will be added in List **B**. And i have done this. List **B** visually show the value, but when I go to the **view source** of the page, I dont see new *<**option**>*.

This is my List **A** options.

[image]

This is my List **B** options (**before and after addition and it remains same whatever items added. this is my problem.**):

[image]

It should have one `<option>`. like

```
<option value="VSNR">VSNR</option>
```

what is my code is :

```
   $('#lstXLSCol').on('dblclick', function () {
        var item = $('#lstXLSCol').find(":selected").text();

        var newOption = { item: item };
        $('option:selected', this).remove();
        $.each(newOption, function (val, text) {
            if (text != "")
                $('#lstXLSSelectedCol').append(new Option(text, val));
        });
    });
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I have found it pressing `F12` in IE. but the values are like below:

[image]

but, i wanted to insert the value same as text. What should be changed in my jquery code?

Comment: Its will not reflect in source page..... press `F12` and inspect your dropdown...you can see the updated `options`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it correct that page elements created by jQuery do not show up in the source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451554/is-it-correct-that-page-elements-created-by-jquery-do-not-show-up-in-the-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#lstXLSSelectedCol:last').live('change', function () {

            var option_selected = $('option:selected', this).val();

                $('#lstXLSSelectedCol:last').append($('<option>', {
                    value: option_selected
                }).text(option_selected));        


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not see them. The source is just used to build the initial [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) that represents the document. Dynamically created elements are only inserted in the DOM.

But you can analyse such elements with a DOM viewer like Safari’s WebInspector or the Firefox extionsion Firebug. Firefox can also show source code that represents such dynamically created elements by selecting that element an choosing *View Selection Source* in the context menu.

**[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451554/is-it-correct-that-page-elements-created-by-jquery-do-not-show-up-in-the-source)**

Answer (score 1):

take out the space between params and :last

```
$('#lstXLSSelectedCol:last').html('<option value=\''+item+'\'>'+item+'</option><option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't see dynamically added elements in the source of your page.

Use your browser's console to inspect the DOM.

Normally it's enough to right click on the element and select "inspect" from the context menu, otherwise see [this link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for how to access your browser's console.

Comment: Your entire code looks a bit weird to me. If you make a fiddle, that'll make life much easier.