# use PHP to append HTML tags to an image

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, append, prepend

I'm trying to add captions to product thumbnails on a WordPress ecommerce site by pulling each image's "alt" tag and adding tags around it to enable me to apply CSS to the caption.

I've found a JQuery script (actually, I've found several) that successfully extracts the "alt" text as a caption, but it doesn't add any of the HTML — or even insert the caption into the page source. So it's there on the front end, but I have no way to select or style it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".thumbnails img.attachment-shop_thumbnail").each(function() {
var caption = $(this).attr("alt");
$(this).before('<figure>');
$(this).after('<figcaption>' + caption + '</figcaption></figure>'
);
});
});
</script>
```

I'm open to using JQuery here, if I can find a script that works; but it occurs to me that PHP might be a better approach. Only problem, I haven't found anything that's even close enough for me to cannibalize . . .

Comment: Ya, you should generate relevant markup server side instead

Comment: agree with wolff. better for performance and pageload and google..

Answer (score 0):

If it's there on the front end, then you should be able to just add markup in your css file at this point and have it show:

```
figcaption {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

etc...
Or, better yet, change figure and figcaption to divs and give them class names.

The reason it's not showing up in the source can be read on this stack overflow question:

[Is it correct that page elements created by jQuery do not show up in the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451554/is-it-correct-that-page-elements-created-by-jquery-do-not-show-up-in-the-source)

Comment: Thanks @rgilligan. I was confused by the fact that the tags didn't appear in the source code, and seemed to be impossible to target effectively using CSS. Turns out the CSS is just a bit finicky about what/how to select; it's working perfectly now (and I did make the change to divs instead of using <figure> and <figcaption>).